# seleniumを使って、見出しからタイトルを全てスクレイピングしたい

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

C#言語にてseleniumを用いたWebスクレイピングを行ってみているのですが、少し詰まってしまった事があるので質問させていただきます。

例としてlivedoorニュース　http://news.livedoor.com/topics/category/main/
にて、上から見出しごとに記事が並んでいます。
これらの記事タイトルを抜き出したいのですが、一番上のものは

```
Chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='main']/div/section/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/div/h3")).Text();
```

などでおそらく取得できるのですが、それより下のものを取得していく方法がわかりません。
どうか教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IWebDriver.FindElement`のかわりに`FindElements`メソッドを使用します。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。少しプログラムを見直しながら試してみます。